# jqgrid editoptions custom_func with required=false

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When I set editrules custom_func and required=false, the custom_func only works if the user enter a value. I mean, if the user leaves the input empty, the custom_func is skipped by jqgrid.
In my case, I want to validate if a field value may be empty or not, depending on other user values from the same row. So I can't set required=false in the colmodel, since I need to validate it after submit.

This is a pseudo-custom_func, don't pay attention on its content:

```
colmodel: [
  {name:'xxx', editrules: {
     required:false, 
     custom:true, 
     custom_func: function(value) {
         if(othercolumn=='blah' && value=='' ) {
             //this is error
         } else {
             //this is correct
         }
     }
  }}
]
```

EDIT: I am using jqGrid 4.6.0 (I am still testing free 4.13.6 in separate branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I think that you posted wrong properties of your code. I guess that you use specify `required`, `custom` and `custom_func` inside of `editrules` and not inside of `editoptions` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules)).

Seconds you should **always** include the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and about the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The possibilities of different versions and different fork of jqGrid are *different*.

To solve your problem you should **don't specify** `required` property in the column or to use `required: undefiled`. Only in case of *explicit* usage of `required: true` the validation will be stopped by empty value. If you specify *explicitly* `required: false`, then `custom_func` will be not called on empty value. Any other values as `true` and `false` of `required` property will allow you to make custom validation.

The next problem, which you have is the requirement to access to the value of *another column* for custom validation. It should be a part of separate question. It's important to know the fork of jqGrid, which you use, the version of jqGrid and the editing mode (inline editing, form editing or cell editing).

Comment: yes is editrules (edited), and jqGrid 4.6.0
You are right, I have a jqgrid wraper which forces default required=false if not declared. So I was delete that default attribute so I can use the custom_func with any value. Thank you!

Comment: About the last problem: "get the value of another input columns", I will post a new question.

Comment: @Aberel: OK. By the way, the code of inline editing **after** 4.13.6 contains new callback `saveRowValidation` , which simplify final validation. The property `newData` (see [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L334-L348)) of the parameter of the callback `saveRowValidation` contain all new (changed) data. It could simplify what you need to implement, if you really use inline editing. See the comment to [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/94b6218f451d62bb3fb1dc5c7b11383c906672ea) for more details.

Comment: Oleg: thanks, I am testing the 4.13.6 and found some troubles which I need to fix in my wrapper. In the meanwhile, I posted a new question for this subject. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655716/jqgrid-custom-func-validation-and-get-all-row-edit-values ). Yes, I use inline edit.

Comment: @Aberel: I posted my answer already. How your "wrapper" looks like? What problem exactly you have?