# Jqgrid custom_func validation and get all row edit values

Tags: jquery, validation, jqgrid

As it commented in another question ([jqgrid editoptions custom_func with required=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650053/jqgrid-editoptions-custom-func-with-required-false/41652115)) , now I need to validate input with custom_func. This validation requires to compare the input value with another columns values entered by the user. In other words, need to get all the current row values before submit to decide the validation result.
I managed to get some specific column this way...

```
function myCustomFunc(value, colName) {
    //consider I have a global var "selRowId" which is updated onSelectRow event.
    var someColValue = $('select#'+selRowId+'_someColName').val();
    // ... here the validation using the "someColValue" ...
}
```

I think this is NOT the best method. I would prefer some method which returns an object similar to "getRowData" but containing all the input values from the user.

I am using jqGrid 4.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use inline editing. jqGrid in the version 4.6 has no other possibilities to access to the current values, but the current sources of free jqGrid (preliminary version 4.13.7 from GitHub) contains new callback `saveRowValidation` and the event `jqGridInlineSaveRowValidation`, which could simplify what you need to implement.

The callback `saveRowValidation` contains one parameter, like the most other callbacks implemented in free jqGrid. The parameter, let us we name it `options`, contains the following properties

- `mode` with the value `"edit"` or `"add"`
- `rowid` - the value of id attribute of the editing row
- `newData` - the object with modified data of the row
- `savedRow` - the object with the data of the row before editing
- `options` - the options of inline editing
- `iRow` - the index of the row from the top of the grid
- `tr` - DOM element, which represent the editing row

I think that `options.newData` is what you need. See the comment to [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/94b6218f451d62bb3fb1dc5c7b11383c906672ea) for more details.

Comment: I think saveRowValidation is a great solution, I would try it as soon as I can implement new version of free jqgrid. 
The current version is 4.13.6? Or 4.13.7?

Comment: @Aberel: The latest *released* version is "4.13.6" (Dec 24, 2016). After making the first changes in the code after the last release I increment the version number (to "4.13.7-pre"). The callback `saveRowValidation` (and event `jqGridInlineSaveRowValidation`) was committed Jan 4, 2017. I publish new version typically ever month. Thus the next "4.13.7" version I plan to published in about 1-2 week.