# Display validation messages at once (validation summary) instead one by one jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

If I have 2 fields in a form that edits grid row and they are all required, when I click submit only message that first field is required is displayed. When I type something in that field and submit then 2nd field validation error is displayed. ... and so on.

Is there a way to display validation messages at once?
this my code

```
 editrules: {                                  
                                custom_func:function (value, colName) {
                                    return validateCheck(value, colName, 'Integer', colNames[i + lenarrtype + 2]);
                                }, 
                                maxlength: colNames[i + lenarrtype + 1],
                                custom: true,
                                required: true
                            },

function validateCheck(value, column, edittype, scalesize) {

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#info_dialog").css({
            left: "25%", // new left position of ERROR dialog
            top: "2%",   // new top position of ERROR dialog

        });
    }, 50);

    switch (edittype) {
        case ('Integer'):
            if (value < 0)
                return [false, column + " :ستون " + "مقدار غیر مجاز"];
            else if (Number(value) === value || value % 1 !== 0) {

                 return [false, column + " :ستون " + " مقدار غیر مجاز "];
            }
            else
                return [true, ""];
            break

        case ('Digit'):

            var scale_splite = value.split('.');
            if (scale_splite.length > 1) {
                if ((scale_splite[1]).length > scalesize) {
                    //return [false, column + " :ستون " + "مقدار اعشار مجاز نیست"];
                }
            }

             if (value < 0)
                return [false, column + " :ستون " + "مقدار غیر مجاز"];
             if (Number(value) === value) {
                return [false, column + " :ستون " + "مقدار غیر مجاز "];

             }
                return [true, ""];
            break
    }

}
```

please this demo :https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/249/

Answer (score 1):

Free jqGrid can makes **two** validations during inline editing: one the standard field validation, which you know from old jqGrid and another, custom final validation, which will be made after every field is validated.

You can remove all validation rules, which you use currently and to add `saveRowValidation` callback instead (for example, inside of `inlineEditing` parameter of jqGrid). The callback get one `options` parameter, which contains the modified data, the old data and some other information described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655786/315935). The callback can return true to inform about successful validation or it can set `errorText` property of `options` to the custom error message and  return false.

```js
inlineEditing: {
    key: true,
    saveRowValidation (options) {
        // options.newData, options.savedRow, options.rowid 

        if (/*some tests of options.newData*/) {
            options.errorText = "your custom error message";
            return false;
        }
        return true; // no error
    }
}
```